# Focusing Body in Outlook MailItem

Tags: vb.net, outlook, vsto, outlook-addin

After filling the "To" I write an automatic salutation to my MailBody. Also I make a Text-Selection after this typed salutation.

```
    m_MailItem.Body = newMailBody
    m_SalutationEntered = True

    With m_WordEditor.Application.Selection
        .Start = newMailBody.IndexOf(vbCrLf & vbCrLf) + 1
    End With
```

This is working fine so far. But after handling this, I have no "real" focus, which means when I press any key, nothing is typed to the body. I can see the cursor but it is not blinking. Hope you understand what I mean.

Comment: What details do you need? The problem is hard to explain. Simply I just want to set focus on the body-textbox and I want to know how this can be archieved.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve Code should start with Option Explicit and end with End Sub

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to find the window handle of the editor (`FindWindow` etc.), then use `SetActiveWindow` / `SetFocus` / `ShowCaret` Windows API functions to focus the editor and show the caret.

If using [Redemption](http://www.dimastr.com/redemption) is an option (I am its author), it exposes [SafeInspector](http://www.dimastr.com/redemption/SafeInspector.htm).`FocusEditor` method:

```
 set sInspector = CreateObject("Redemption.SafeInspector")
 sInspector.Item = Application.ActiveInspector
 sInspector.FocusEditor
```